# How to make PyOpenGL's title show Chinese

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

Code is here.

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
import sys


def initial():
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluOrtho2D(-10.0, 10.0, -10.0, 10.0)

def Display():
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    glViewport(0, 0, 200, 200)
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    glViewport(200, 0, 200, 200)
    glFlush()


def main():
    glutInit(sys.argv)
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB)
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100)
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 200)
    glutCreateWindow("一二三四")
    initial()
    glutDisplayFunc(Display)
    glutMainLoop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The title is "一二三四", but it turns out to be [image]

I don't want to change from UTF-8 to GBK, so is there any way to solve it?

> As far as I know, glfw can support Chinese. But I am not familiar with it.

My Python version is 3.7.0 32-bit

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @KenKinder 3.7.0 32-bit Window10 x64 1803

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some test, I find the solution:

Just need to change

```py
glutCreateWindow("一二三四")
```

to

```py
glutCreateWindow("一二三四".encode("gb2312"))
```